# Align two lines of text inside a \emailfrom

Tags: horizontal-alignment, letters, newlfm

I am very new to TeX and I am trying to do a simple cover letter using LaTeX. I've downloaded a template for a cover letter and it has a component (don't know how you call these things) named `\emailfrom`. My code looks like this:

```
\emailfrom{ % Email address
first.email@email.com \\
second.email@email.com \\
third.email@email.com
}
```

This is what I am currently obtaining:

[image: Problem of alignment]

My only inelegant solution so far is:

```
\emailfrom{ % Email address
first.email@email.com \\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~second.email@email.com \\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~third.email@email.com
}
```

I would like to be able to align second and third email to the first one. How can I achieve this?

Sorry for the vagueness but I am clueless about TeX.

Comment: Are you using the [`newlfm` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm)?

Comment: yes, I am using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested in the absence of a MWE. Try some thing like this:

```
\emailfrom{% Email address
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
first.email@email.com \\
second.email@email.com \\
third.email@email.com
\end{tabular}
}
```

To get hyperlinks and `mailto: put`\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble, and use

```
\href{mailto:your name}{first.email}
```

Comment: How can I include mailto to the links? I've tried but gives me an error. Thank you.

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion -- The package `hyperref` is required for the `\href` macro.

Comment: Note that you should also actually use a `@{}l@{}` column specification, as the `l` alone adds a `\tabcolsep` space on either end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another "funny" answer which canot be accepted because TeX primitives (used here) are not explained in LaTeX guides, unfortunately.

```
% in preamble:
\def\emails#1{\vtop\bgroup\emailsA #1,,}
\def\emailsA#1,{\ifx,#1,\egroup\else\hbox{\ignorespaces#1}\expandafter\emailsA\fi}

% in document:
Emails: \emails{first.email@email.com, second.email@email.com, third.email@email.com}
```

Comment: You should have `\leavevmode` before `\vtop`. Why should this be simpler than `\newcommand{\emails}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}` called as `\emails{a@b.c \\ d@e.f \\ g@h.i}` that needs no fancy trick with spaces?

Comment: @egreg We needn't `\leavevmode` because `\emails` is used at the end of the paragraph. If it is used in vertical mode, no problem. Your suggestion with `tabular` is simpler from one point of view. It expands to `\vtop{\halign{...}}` (note, without `\leavevmode`). My answer shows, what should be done at primitive level: `\vtop{\hbox{}\hbox{}\hbox{}}`. I prefer hboxes if there is only one left aligned column but this isn't probably based on any good arguments.

Comment: Of course `\begin{tabular}` does `\tabular` which ends with `\@tabular`. And this macro starts with, guess what, `\leavevmode`. I could understand not using it if “Emails:” had been incorporated in it; as the macro is defined, `\leavevmode` is definitely needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox,hyperref}

\newcounter{email}
\newcommand{\emailfrom}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \parindent 0pt%
  \parbox{2cm}{Email:}%
  \setcounter{email}{0}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{email}%
    \ifnum\value{email}<2\relax%
    \emailformat{##1}\par
    \else
    \hspace{2cm}\emailformat{##1}\par
  \fi}%
  \docsvlist{#1}
  \endgroup}
\newcommand{\emailformat}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\emailfrom{% Email address
first.email@email.com, second.email@email.com, third.email@email.com}

\end{document}
```

It sets a counter called 'email' so that you can make the first item in the list behave differently than those that follow.  The command `\emailformat` is used so you can style the email addresses more easily. The parameters for `\parindent` and `\parindent` should be changed to taste.  (They could -- if you like -- be incorporated into the definition to `\emailfrom` so you can change them at the time you issue the command.)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I accepted Harish Kumar answer since it is the simplest and the one I understand even though yours works too (and includes \href{mailto:} which I knew nothing about). Yours is too advanced for me.

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion -- No problem. As long as your question is answered.  (Plus, sometimes the best answers aren't necessarily the *funnest* ones to write....)